# A title of the form : \section{The space $\mathbb{S}^2_{\square}$} not working

Tags: pdftex, symbols, amsmath

I am trying to use a math symbol in my title but it's not working. Precisely, I wanna write

```
\section{The space $\mathbb{S}^2_{\square}$}
```

and it's not working at all. And by the way in the text: `$\mathbb{S}^2_{\square}$` shows perfectly. Also, if I remove `_{\square}` and I take only

```
\section{The space $\mathbb{S}^2$}
```

it works. So I don't understand why it's so complicated to solve this issue.

Do you have any ideas of solutions ? thanks.

NB: In overleaf for some reason this is no longer an issue, but I work with texstudio.

Comment: Please, make a short example of code starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` that exhibits the behavior. Note that "it's not working at all” is not really helpful in order to debug your issue.

Comment: I use \documentclass[a4paper,nobind, 4pt]{unilim} and unlim.cls it the file that contains all the packages. (it is a 'big' thesis file)

Comment: Please provide the class file.@hanava331

Comment: Sorry, but you in order to debug we still need a minimal example and, in this case, also a pointer to the class file.

Comment: you presumably have a fragile definition of `\square` and can use `\protect\square` but you should provide an example

Answer (score 3):

```
! Argument of \__siunitx_unit_literal_power:nn has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \section{The space $\mathbb{S}^2_{\square}$}
                                                
?
```

`siunix` and `amssymb` disagreeing about `\square`, easiest is to use the alternative name `\Box`

```
\documentclass{unilim}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{The space $\mathbb{S}^2_{\Box}$}
x
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: class from the link in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903533/why-pdflatex-on-overleaf-and-my-laptop-gives-different-output